# Reversing a SSL certificate from SHA-256

Tags: ssl, sha

I have an android app with SPKI pinning enabled. Cloud flare rotated the certificates and now I have no access to application. Is there way to generate certificate with similar SHA-256? Any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Generating a certificate with a "similar" hash would not be enough, it must be the same. And if that was possible, certficates would be worthless. Why not provide an update to that app with a new certificate?

Comment: The update is not possible since devices don't use Google play services and update itself. And the app is not using certificate pinning, it only has SHA-256 of the old certificate

Comment: Your app has an embedded SHA-256 hash that it uses to verify a certificate of a service it connects to?  And that service is now using a new certificate?  And your apps can't connect to the service now?  If that's true, you need to deploy new versions of the app some other way.  Hopefully this time with a robust, sustainable way to validate server certificates.